# Maven run configuration doesn't pick up active profile while Spring run configuration does

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

My Spring run configuration is just the default with the following the VM options:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

---

My Maven run configuration is the defaults with the following in the command line:

```
spring-boot:run
```

and the following in VM options:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

---

When I run the maven one it doesn't pick up on a profile and instead uses default:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

With the Spring configuration I have no issues, the problem is with how I need to deploy it, it uses a maven command, so I can't have this failing and I don't really understand why it's happening. There really isn't anything fancy is this projects. It's your basic micro service.

Just in case it's needed. The root 'Application' file only has the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Link to the Maven run config. It is all defaults outside of what is pictured. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE2vp.jpg

Comment: do you have local profile in application.yml or properties ?

Comment: Nope, I can put it in there but it doesn't fix the problem. Since it ignores the vm options. Every run will just use whatever I entering in the application.properties

Comment: can you update properties file, if you don't have profiles in properties file it will ignore it

Comment: I added spring.profiles.active=local to application.properties which makes it run in local, but now even if I do -Dspring.profiles.active=test , it still runs in local because it's ignoring the vm options still.

Comment: okay you can do this in two ways, one VM options, second command line args, if you can pass it like command line args `--spring.profiles.active=local`

Comment: if you are running in eclipse, add this to env variables, or running like `java -jar` command then do like this `java -jar jar name --spring.active.profiles=local`

Comment: Running in intellij. I tried --spring.profiles.active=local in the command line but it immediately fails because it tries to run --spring.profiles.active=local through maven and blows up. "Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --spring.profiles.active=local"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183660/discussion-between-deadpool-and-canpan14).

Comment: can you add the run ocnfiguration you referenced

Comment: I added pictures of the maven config (all defaults except for what is typed in) https://imgur.com/a/GGiwimQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to the command line arguments seemed to fix it:

```
-Drun.jvmArguments=-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Although I understand why it worked it doesn't explain why this happened in the first place. I will update this answer if I ever find out the true reason.

Answer (score -1):

create

```
application.properties
```

file in src/main/resources if it doesnt exist and add

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

Comment: wouldn't that make it so no matter how it runs, it runs in local? So I couldn't set it to dev/test through the vm options because the application.properties would override it. I've also never had to do that for another project.

Comment: the vm options override the application.properties file for the same properties

Comment: But if the vm options aren't working it will never override it. (And I just tested it, it remains local no matter what I put in the vm options)